# When were airbrakes used for the first time in aviation?

Tags: aerodynamics, aviation-history, airbrakes

I would like to have some information about the history of airbrakes.

Comment: Guess that was in first world war. The stukas needed it for their dive.

Comment: @NoahKrasser: Stukas? First world war? I think you got your wars confused.

Comment: i saw from discovery channel p38 lightning was crashing because it was so fast at diving, no other plane fast like it before, and engineers started to place some sort air spoilers to slow down plane at diving. and i guess no other planes that fast before even when diving because lack of good aerodynamics design induces high drag when diving. this is not answer but i guess it is answering, what is the first necessary airbrake?

Comment: by the way discovery channel states, engineers wasnt aware of air behavior over certain speed before.

Comment: Airbrakes were probably used on gliders first (for quick landing).

Comment: @FredLarson Ah, sure, thanks! Of course second world war! Don't know why I wrote "first".

Answer (score 5):

[image]
(*Flight* magazine 1914)

I'll answer the title question, as the complete history is too broad. That would be the [Avro Scout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_511) (model 511) of c. 1914. Only one was built. Yes, that suspiciously looks like flaps. Back then +100 years ago that invention was called an air brake, flaps *are* air brakes after all.

From Wikipedia:

> Most unusually for its time, the inboard lower wing featured <strike>landing flaps</strike> air brakes, so the 511 landed at a sedate 35 mph (56 km/h).

This is what the plane looked like:

[image]

Comment: Notice the streamlined covered wing struts, slick!